# How to get user ip, when user login with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, devise, ip

I am working with security in my app. How Can I show recaptcha in devise login form if user login x times with failure ? I think the best solution is checking IP and set recaptcha after x times. There's some tutorial or something for Rails ?

Answer (score 0):

This  [Login Security](https://hakiri.io/blog/rails-login-security) link will may help you.

Here you need to Devise :lockable module

Comment: This tutorial is locking account,not secured for brute force attack. Example: I have 2 accounts in db and I know emails. I can attack first email to block account and I can attack second account x times to block. So query is created to db to find account. But problem above should be solved by block any request to SessionsController for IP